# Why should we use Dynamic Programming with Memoization in order to solve - Minimum Number of Coins to Make Change

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

> [The Problem Statement](http://www.ideserve.co.in/learn/minimum-number-of-coins-to-make-change):
>   Given an infinite supply of coins of values {C1, C2, ..., Cn} and a sum, find the minimum number of coins that can represent the sum X.

Most of the solutions on the web include **dynamic programming with memoization**. Here is an example from Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kf_M7RdHr1M

My question is: why don't we **sort the array of coins in descending order first** and start exploring recursively by minimizing the sum until we reach 0? When we reach 0, we know that we have found the needed coins to make up the sum. Because we sorted the array in descending order, we know that we will always choose the greatest coin. Therefore, the first time the sum reaches down to 0, the count will have to be minimum.

I'd greatly appreciate if you help understand the complexity of my algorithm and compare it to the dynamic programming with memoization approach.

For simplicty, we are assuming there will always be a "$1" coin and thus there is always a way to make up the sum.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Solution{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        MinCount cnt=new MinCount(new Integer []{1,2,7,9});
        System.out.println(cnt.count(12));
    }
}

class MinCount{
     Integer[] coins;

     public MinCount(Integer [] coins){
        Arrays.sort(coins,Collections.reverseOrder());
        this.coins=coins;
    }

     public int count(int sum){
        if(sum<0)return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if(sum==0)return 0;     
        int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0; i<coins.length; i++){
            int val=count(sum-coins[i]);    
            if(val<min)min=val;
            if(val!=Integer.MAX_VALUE)break;
        }
        return min+1;
     }
}
```

Comment: Imagine the value 13 with coins of 5, 4 and 2 as example for a problem that can't be naively solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that you have coins worth $1, $50, and $52, and that your total is $100. Your proposed algorithm would produce a solution that uses 49 coins ($52 + $1 + $1 + … + $1 + $1); but the correct minimum result requires only 2 coins ($50 + $50).

(Incidentally, I think it's cheating to write

> For simplicty we are assuming there will always be a "$1" coin and thus there is always a way to make up the sum.

when this is not in the problem statement, and therefore not assumed in other sources. That's a bit like asking "Why do sorting algorithms always put a lot of effort into rearranging the elements, instead of just assuming that the elements are in the right order to begin with?" But as it happens, even assuming the existence of a $1 coin doesn't let you guarantee that the naïve/greedy algorithm will find the optimal solution.)

Answer (score 4):

I will complement the answer that has already been provided to your question with some algorithm design advice.

The solution that you propose is what is called a "greedy algorithm": a problem solving strategy that makes the locally optimal choice at each stage with the hope of finding a global optimum.

In many problems, a greedy strategy does not produce an optimal solution. **The best way to disprove the correctess of an algorithm is to find a counter-example**, such as the case of the "$52", "$50", and "$1" coins. To find counter-examples, Steven Skiena gives the following advice in his book "The Algorithm Design Manual":

> - **Think small**: when an algorithm fails, there is usually a very simple example on which it fails.
> - **Hunt for the weakness**: if the proposed algorithm is of the form "always take the biggest" (that is, a greedy algorithm), think about why that might prove to be the wrong thing to do. In particular, ...
> - **Go for a tie**: A devious way to break a greedy algorithm is to provide instances where everything is the same size. This way the algorithm may have nothing to base its decision on.
> - **Seek extremes**: many counter-examples are mixtures of huge and tiny, left and right, few and many, near and far. It is usually easier to verify or reason about extreme examples than more muddled ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
#recursive solution in python
import sys
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ans=0
        self.maxint=sys.maxsize-1
    def minCoins(self, coins, m, v):
        res=self.solve(coins,m,v)
        if res==sys.maxsize-1:
            return -1
        return res
        
    def solve(self,coins,m,v):
        if m==0 and v>0:
            return self.maxint
        if v==0:
            return 0
        
        if coins[m-1]<=v:
            self.ans=min(self.solve(coins,m,v-coins[m-1])+1,self.solve(coins,m-1,v))
            return self.ans
        else:
            self.ans=self.solve(coins,m-1,v)
            return self.ans
```